# Unique query based off another column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So, I'd like to get a bunch of ids based on uniqness of another column.

```
[1,'A']
[2,'B']
[3,'C']
[4,'A']
```

I'd like to return [1,2,3] (losing the 4th because 'A' is no longer unique). I've tried `.select('DISTINCT letter, id')` and some grouping, but I can't seem get it.

My database is PostgreSQL. SQL or ActiveRecord is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best solution, but it works with Postgres.

```
Model.select("min(id) as id, letter").group(:letter).map(&:id)
```

**EDIT:**
Actually, I found an even better (read: shorter) solution.

```
Model.group(:letter).pluck("min(id)")
```

**ANOTHER EDIT:**
I've found a solution that works without aggregation (min or max).

```
Model.select("distinct on (letter) letter, id").map(&:id)
```

Comment: close!! that gives an array strings, though.

Comment: @Mallanaga I'm not sure what you mean by "array strings". Plucking `min(id)` will give you an array of integers assuming `id` is an integer column. Did you use your first column in your example as the id column?

Comment: oddly enough, it didn't. id is definitely an integer column. I just added `.map(&:to_i)` at the end of your pluck, and it's good to go

Comment: Huh. That's certainly bizarre. In the [rails documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck), it says the `pluck` returns an array of strings by default, but in the examples listed every `:id` pluck returns an array of integers. Weird.

Comment: in the last case above, will this always return 1 or 4? or will it be mixed?

Comment: No, it seems like it will be mixed.